# How can I create Side Navigation like with border on left like image?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css, vue-router4

I want to create side navigation like this in Vue3, with active class.
I want to add border-left like in the image.

[image]

Currently I have it like this.
[image]

SideBar.vue

```
  <div class="flex flex-col space-y-9 mt-4 -mx-6 ">
                <RouterLink v-for="(mu, idx) in menu" :key="idx" class="flex  text-[#A09F9F] cursor-pointer "
                    :to="mu.route">
                    <img :src="mu.icon" class="w-6 h-6 mr-2 ml-3" />
                    <span class="text-center text-lg">{{ mu.text }} </span>
                </RouterLink>
            </div>
```

router.js

[image]

.active class

```
.active {
    color: #3C59A8 !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #E8E9EA 0%, #FAFAFA 100%);
    transition: .2s;
    border-left: #3C59A8 4px solid;

}
```

I want make the border as in the first image, rounded border from left side.

Thank you.

I have tried border left, didn't work, tried to add ::before with that it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a new div on the left-hand side of the active link so I could use border-right CSS properties on it

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-wood-gcik9g?file=/src/App.vue:655-660)

not exactly the same setup as yours, but hopefully it still makes sense conceptually.

```html
  <div class="flex flex-col space-y-9 mt-4">
    <div
      v-for="(mu, idx) in menu"
      :key="idx"
      class="link cursor-pointer relative"
      :to="mu.route"
      @click="changeActive(idx)"
    >
      <div v-if="mu.active" class="active"></div>
      <span class="text-center text-lg ml-5">{{ mu.text }} </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```css
.link {
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.active {
  color: #3c59a8 !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #e8e9ea 0%, #fafafa 100%);
  height: 100%;
  border-right: #3c59a8 8px solid;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px 30px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: I did modify according to your example, but it didn't work as expected.